# Alternatives to node-pty for Bun

Tags: node.js, bun, node-pty

I am writing the backend for an administration Web interface and started the work with Node.js. To provide terminal functionality I used the node-pty package. Since bundling with TypeScript and Node.js is not that easy, I wanted to switch to Bun. The switch was really simple except for the node-pty package.

Is there any package I can use to provide PTY data to a websocket? Does an application exist for bridging the needed calls between the system and bun? My goal is to find a replacement for `node-pty` that does not need a lot of changes in code while being as integrated to `Bun` as possible.

Thank you very much for your help.